# Highest number of public holidays in country/region

Tags: public-holidays

According to a [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holiday), Nepal has the highest number of public holidays in the world.

> With 36 days a year, Nepal is the country with the highest number of public holidays but it observes six working days a week.

Any similar examples? Seems this article is bit old.

Comment: I assume people don't think this question is a suitable one for Politics.  It might fit better on Travel (but don't take my word for that).

Comment: It seems suitable to me. The designation of national holidays is a political decision and it is legitimate to ask why some have more than others. A brief glance at the Indian holidays would suggest that part of the reason is the number of different religions.

Comment: It's not really sensible to put the answer to your question in the question itself.  You should instead move your answer to an actual answer.

Comment: Note that the raw number is not the only factor. In some countries, if a public holiday is at the weekend then that’s just tough luck, while in others (e.g. the UK) it will be relocated to the closest week day. So the countries in the first group have fewer holidays in practice than the number you will get just by counting a list of holidays.

Comment: @JoeC I am looking for a region/country with more number of holidays.

Comment: @MikeScott I agree with what you have said. The beautiful observation here is India is more inclusive. She cares about and respects the various groups of people and what they value most. Indians get the absolute privilege to visit a Muslim during Eid, or a Hindu during their Puja, or a Sikh during their festival without taking a leave from work.

Comment: If that is what you are looking for, then you would be more likely to get an answer if you removed what appears to be a suggestion about what the answer might be.

Comment: How do you define a public holiday? From your question it seems that it's not necessarily a day on which most (public sector) workers get a day off. Does it just mean the day is recognized as a holiday by the government? I think different definitions might yield different answers. I also don't really get your inclusivity argument. If workers get to choose their own days off from all working days, then isn't that more inclusive by not limiting them to choose from pre-approved holidays?

Comment: @JJJ 1. Does it just mean the day is recognized as a holiday by the government? - Yes. Sometimes they fall on Sundays, then the holidays go waste. 2. If workers get to choose their own days off from all working days, then isn't that more inclusive by not limiting them to choose from pre-approved holidays? - That would be a leave. Are you talking about leave? Anyone can take that. Or are you talking about the restricted holiday. Actually restricted holiday is one which has some religious or cultural significance. One can choose two such days as an optional holiday.

Comment: @JJJ From your question it seems that it's not necessarily a day on which most (public sector) workers get a day off. - Everyone gets a holiday in the gazetted holiday. That number is 35. Also, everyone in a district gets holiday in the local holiday, that number varies. Here it is possibly 1. I'm not very sure about it. It might be more.

Comment: Since you're asking which country has the most public holidays, it would be better to put those criteria in your question. Then your example of India can go in an answer instead. The way the question is written now might discourage others from answering because it's not clear if their suggestions fit the question.

Comment: @JJJ is this alright now?

Comment: Yea, I think it's better that the question and answer are separated now. I still think the question lacks a clear definition of what a public holiday is.

Answer (score 4):

See this calender of an Indian state called Assam. It has 35 holidays. The state offers 2 days parental holiday as well. [Parental holiday](https://m.timesofindia.com/city/guwahati/assam-gives-4-days-parental-leave-ministers-not-entitled-to-leave-but-allowed-some-time-off/articleshow/87899634.cms) and 35 makes it 37.  There are also 2 half days, which I am not counting.

[image: 20211213-131904.png]

India has 2 days restricted holidays provision where if an employee choose may take holiday on any such two days of the year. A Christian can take restricted holiday on 24 December (Christmas Eve), a Hindu may take one on Shivratri and other festivals, a Muslim may take one on Muharram. These holidays are like leaves and are not counted as general leaves (casual, commuted, or earned). These 2 with 37 makes 39.

There is almost always a local holiday in that state, that power lies with the district commissioner. That makes it 40.

So, it gives 35 + 2 (parental) + 2 (restricted) + 1 (local) = 40 days.

Comment: Hm, and if there are holidays on the 23rd, 25th and 26th (Jan), probably nobody really works on the 24th...

Answer (score 1):

There are [53 listed public holidays in Malaysia](https://publicholidays.com.my/2021-dates/), with the caveat that many of the holidays are at state level. For example 2 Oct is the Sabah Governor's birthday, celebrated only in the state of Sabah. I did not check each individual state to see which has the highest number of holidays.

Comment: Please answer only one state or country.